# Neo4j, how to get all "parrents" for a "child" if there are more than one?

Tags: neo4j

Finally I got the first draft of the database having two nodes: Authors and Books. Everything was created following the blog example. In my model Authors replaces Posts and Books replaces Comments. I have also a relationship from Authors to Books, so practically 3 model classes. I am using RoR. I am able to perform CRUD for Authors and Books. Everything works well. In a nutshell Authors are the "parent" and the Books are the "children" if considering an analogy with relational databases. Here is my question. In the show for one book using
<%= @book.title %>
<%= @book.author.name %>
I can see only the last author. There are no books there without at least one author, but some books may have more than one. How I can list them all?

Comment: I am able to run this query start n=node(1) match n-[:authored_book]-(m) return n,m; successfully from the neo4j-shell and I am getting a book under "n" with both authors listed under "m".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading on https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Search-and-Match
I was able to figure out the solution which is:

```
title = Book.first.title
result = Author.query_as(:author).match("author-[:authored_book]->(book:Book)").where(book: {title: title}).pluck(:author, :book)
result.count

result.each do |author, book|
  puts book.title
  puts author.name
end

result.each do |author,book|
  puts author.name
end
```

And it is working as expected.